# How to change style color of elements with the same class name based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change a color of a <div> element based on a condition (ex. if the number is <=3).

My HTML code (or most of it) is constructed with insertAdjacentHTML and in each loop I end up getting only the first element with the querySelector.

I tried using querySelectorAll after the loop but this gives me an empty result.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sorting">
        <div class="filter">
          <div class="filter-sort"><b>Filter by</b></div>
          <select class="dropdown filter-by" id="list_two" name="filter" >
            <option value="depasc">Departure Date</option>
            <option value="jan">January</option>
            <option value="feb">February</option>
            <option value="mar">March</option>
            <option value="apr">April</option>
            <option value="may">May</option>
            <option value="jun">June</option>
            <option value="jul">July</option>
            <option value="aug">August</option>
            <option value="sept">September</option>
            <option value="oct">October</option>
            <option value="nov">November</option>
            <option value="dec">December</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="filter">
          <div class="filter-sort"><b>Sort by</b></div>
            <select class="dropdown sort" id="list_one" name="sort">
              <option value="popasc">Popularity: Most popular first</option>
              <option value="prasc">Price: Lowest first</option>
              <option value="prdesc">Price: Highest first</option>
              <option value="durasc">Duration: Shortest first</option>
              <option value="durdesc">Duration: Longest first</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="box-id">
        // Here comes the added HTML from JS side                
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS code (snippet from what gets rendered in a loop 10 times for 10 elements) :

```
const html = `<div class="date">
              <div class="from-date1">
                <div class="from-date">${getDate(dates[0])}</div>
                <div class="spaces-left" id="sl1">${checkAvailableSpaces(availableSpaces,0)} spaces left</div>
              </div>
              <div class="from-date2">
                  <div class="from-date">${getDate(dates[1])}</div>
                  <div class="spaces-left" id="sl2">${checkAvailableSpaces(availableSpaces,1)} spaces left</div>
              </div>
            </div>`

box.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

if(availableSpaces.length > 0){
          let b = 0;
          while (b <= 1) {
            console.log(b);
            console.log(availableSpaces[b],'SPACES');
            if(availableSpaces[b] <= 3){
              console.log("NUmber is smaller than 3");
              console.log(document.querySelector('.spaces-left'));
              document.querySelector('.spaces-left').style.color = 'red';
            }
            b++;
          }
        }
```

Example of what the page looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vmZN.png)

As seen, here even when the condition is not true the color is changed but only for the first element. In each iteration, the querySelector

```
document.querySelector('.spaces-left')
```

always return the first element with the class name "spaces-left".

Comment: You must use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

use `querySelectorAll` as `querySelector` only selects the first element only where as `querySelectorAll` selects all.

**Note:**
I can see that your code is going to make an error. It is going to selectAll the `.spaces-left` without the check of condition whether the spaces are less than 3 or not. To solve the error I might require the complete function.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried with the querySelectorAll, looped through it and set up the condition. Worked perfectly!